# Info not sending through ajax to php file

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to have a submit button send to a php file and then give a popup notification its been completed. Currently when I run the following, it simply gives me the notification however no info is posted. It then redirects to an empty search.php with no post data. I need it to simply give the popup, submit the info, and stay on the same page. I cant seem to figure out what's wrong with my form

HTML:

```
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                    <form class="request" action="search.php" method="POST">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <form role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <p>WO notations appear at the top of the work order screen. Only submit useful information that can be provided to builders/centerpoint. Other importation information may include bricks, scaffles, dogs, or home owners preventing installation. Be sure to include phone numbers if available.</p>
                                    <label>Information</label>
                                    <div><input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter information here" type="text" name="Comment[]"></div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" name="notation" class="btn btn-default" onClick="AddNotation(<?php echo $orow['WorkOrder']; ?>);">Submit Button</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Button</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Ajax

```
<!-- Notation -->
<script>
function AddNotation(wo)
    {
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions/woNotation.php",
            data: 'wo='+wo,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response)
        {
                alert("Your notation has been added to this work order");


        }
                    });
    }


 </script>
```

PHP (woNotation.php)

```
<?php

include("../../db.php");

$woid = $_POST['wo'];
$date = date('m-d-Y');
$notationsql = "INSERT INTO Comments (WorkOrder, Comment, Priority, Date) VALUES ('".$woid."', '".$_POST['Comment']."', '1', '".$date"')";
mysql_query($notationsql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: You've probably already heard this, but in general prepare statements are much nicer than query concatenation. Back to the point, have you tested if the sql query works?

Comment: Query works fine for me in testing

Comment: Can you post search.php? Thanks

Comment: It's 419 lines. The relevant information is posted already. The only other information would be that POST data is sent to it to display results from multiple sql queries. Then of course I have this notation section.

Comment: I don't see a `return false;` or `event.preventDefault();` inside your `AddNotation()` function to prevent the default action, and post by Ajax.

Comment: (1) have you looked at the resulting source code for the HTML to make sure you have a value in `onClick="AddNotation(<?php echo $orow['WorkOrder']; ?>);"`. (2) You have `$_POST['Comment']` in your query, but you only send `wo` and not `Comment` in your Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the data to something like this:

```
data: {wo: wo}
```

Comment: Doing `data : {wo : wo}` is easier to read, but results in the same result as `data : 'wo'+wo`, as per the docs - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - *data
Type: PlainObject or String or Array
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.*

Comment: I still get the same results

Comment: It's 419 lines. The relevant information is posted already. The only other information would be that POST data is sent to it to display results from multiple sql queries. Then of course I have this notation section.

Answer (score 0):

HTML CODE

```
<form name="exampleform">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter information here" type="text" name="Comment[]">
    <input type="hidden" name="woData" value="<?php echo $orow['WorkOrder']; ?>">
</form>
```

In you javascript file.

```
jQuery('form[name="exampleform"]').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions/woNotation.php",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            if (response === "SUCCESS") {
                alert("Your notation has been added to this work order");
            }
            else { 
                //do something
            }
        }
    });
});
```

PHP woNotation.php

```
<?php
    include("../../db.php");
    $woid = $_POST['woData'];
    $date = date('m-d-Y');
    $notationsql = "INSERT INTO Comments (WorkOrder, Comment, Priority, Date) VALUES ('".$woid."', '".$_POST['Comment']."', '1', '".$date"')";
    $data = mysql_query($notationsql) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILURE";
    echo $data;
?>
```

You can also check for console.log(response) if there is a sting "FAILURE" in your log that means the problem is  with your db.php file due to which mysql_query is not working.

Comment: Did you notice the OP has `$_POST['Comment']` in the php code query, but it is nowhere in their original Ajax or your version either?

Comment: Yes it's not defined any where and the ajax is only sending the parameter wodata, What needs is to serialize the form before ajax request.
`var formData = $(this).serialize()`

Comment: and put the formData in to ajax like `data: formData,`
and change in PHP `$woid = $_POST['woData'];`

Comment: If this is not solved yet, Please let me know I will try to run the environment on my machine and will update your with the code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="request" action="search.php" method="POST">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>WO notations appear at the top of the work order screen. Only submit useful information that
                            can be provided to builders/centerpoint. Other importation information may include bricks,
                            scaffles, dogs, or home owners preventing installation. Be sure to include phone numbers if
                            available.</p>
                        <label>Information</label>

                        <div><input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter information here" type="text"
                                    name="Comment[]"></div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="notation" class="btn btn-default"
                            onClick="return AddNotation(<?php echo $orow['WorkOrder']; ?>);">Submit Button
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Button</button>
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function AddNotation(wo) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions/woNotation.php",
            data: {'wo': wo},
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Your notation has been added to this work order");


            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not helpful. Please provide an explanation of the code you have provided, and why it will help the OP resolve the issue they are having.